# runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.throwfornonsuccess

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I am running .net application which fetches data from SQL database and displays on the form screen.
When I run the application in UAT, it works fine but in PROD, I am getting below exception
[image: Error]

Query run fine on database but I am getting this exception.

PricingClinet.cs -

```
 public async Task<SaveResponse> SaveAsync(Sheet sheet)
        {
            SaveResponse result = null;

            try
            {
                var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("Pricing/Save", sheet);

                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SaveResponse>(jsonResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    var errorMessage = string.Format("StatusCode: {0}\r\n{1}", response.StatusCode.ToString(), response.ReasonPhrase);
                    Logger.LogError(errorMessage);
                    result = new SaveResponse()
                    {
                        Success = false,
                        ErrorMessage = errorMessage
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Logger.LogError(error);
                result = new SaveResponse()
                {
                    Success = false,
                    ErrorMessage = ExceptionManager.RenderErrorMessage(error)
                };
            }

            return result;
        }
```

This error is hapenning in PROD only, not in UAT.

Comment: I don't see the relevant code (`MoveNext` in a lambda). Also most likely you are getting a timeout on SQL Server, which would be very dependent on what query you are running and the indexes to support it.

Comment: `var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("Pricing/Save", sheet);` looks like a primary suscpect and "Task was cancelled" is likely to be because the remote server didn't respond.

Answer (score 1):

This is a timeout in a `await _client.PostAsJsonAsync`.

You need to confirm that your PROD configuration is correct e.g. points to the correct server.

If your configuration is correct then you need to either increase the timeout
(e.g. `_client.Timeout = ...`) or make the remote call faster (if it's in your control obviously).